# Intellisense for extension methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, extension-methods, intellisense

Is there a way to get intellisense for extension methods from classes that are not currently within the usings, but referenced in the solution. It would be great convenience to be able to just type and not have to add the using when using an extension method the first time in a class.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more in detail what you mean with 'speculative intellisense'?

Comment: Resharper does not do "speculative intellisense" as you put it.  It simply will not suggest anything that is not visible via the current usings.  This is why it won't suggest something, but if you type it out fully, it will suggest to add the using if the assembly is referenced.

Comment: @Mystere Man You are wrong, see Metro Smurf's answer.

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy - Well, what do you know.  Even old goats can learn something new.  However, it's not quite what I expected.. it *ONLY* shows non-visible includes, it doesn't provide a unified view of both visible and non-visible types.  Still, very useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the [Import Symbol Creation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Code_Completion__Type_Name.html) with Re#. I use this all the time when accessing members that are not part of the current using statements. In essence, Re# will look through all your referenced assemblies and see if anything matches and then provide a list of those possible matches and import if needed.

> Import Symbol Completion (formerly known as Type Name Completion)
>   displays all types that match a given prefix regardless of what
>   namespace they belong to (as opposed to Symbol Completion, which only
>   completes names of currently visible types). Import Symbol Completion
>   automatically inserts appropriate namespace import directives to the
>   current file if a selected type has not been imported previously. It
>   also works after dot with extension methods and puts necessary using
>   directives.

The default Re# key mapping is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

I'm not sure if I updated my mappings, but I have to use: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>

Comment: Correct key mapping on VS keyboard scheme is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>. Documentation gives IDEA-style shortcut.

Comment: I tried it and it works even better than I could have imagined!