# Extension method on interface with variance parameter doesn't show up in IntelliSense

Tags: c#, visual-studio, extension-methods, intellisense

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IInterface<out T> {
    T Value { get; }
}
```

and two extension method (in the same namespace as interface):

```
public static class InterfaceExtensions
{
    public static void ExtensionAny<T>(this IInterface<T> ifc) { }
    public static void ExtensionEnumerable<T>(this IInterface<IEnumerable<T>> ifc) { }
}
```

Following code compiles without any problems:

```
IInterface<IEnumerable<string>> enumerable = null;
IInterface<IList<string>> list = null;

enumerable.ExtensionAny(); enumerable.ExtensionEnumerable();

list.ExtensionAny(); list.ExtensionEnumerable();
```

but Visual Studio doesn't show `ExtensionEnumerable` in IntelliSense on `list` variable.

I already tried to reset VisualStudio settings and removed all custom extensions, but it didn't help. I also tried to use `IInterface<IList<string>>` from VisualBasic.NET and it *shows* `ExtensionEnumerable` in IntelliSense.

What worse some of my friends have this method on thier IntelliSense list while others don't - it doesn't depend on ReSharper.

I simply want to have IntelliSense for `ExtensionEnumerable` method, any suggestions?

Comment: Does the code compile if you manually write the call to the extension method? If it does, it might be a bug in VS. You can report it on Connect.

Comment: Which version (VS2008, VS2012, ...) and edition (express, ultimate, ...) of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @Thomas it compiles without any problems, if no answers appear within a week I will report it on Connect.

Comment: @Piotr I tested it on VS 2014 Pro Update 3 with a bunch of extensions and on VS Community 2013 Update 4 (fresh install).

Comment: Did you check this thread? That might be your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849834/intellisense-for-extension-methods

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski my problem is not about _all_ extension methods not showing in IntelliSense but about a single method `ExtensionEnumerable` not showing itself in IS on variable `list`. What's more it works on some of my friends computers, I think it a problem with VS configuration or with some extension...